# Native iPhone app using PHP/Ruby

Tags: iphone, cordova, rhomobile

I am new in iPhone development, and am trying to study the Objective-C language to develop my native app. Somewhere I heard that we can develop native apps for iPhone using PHP/Ruby with the help of third party tools like Phonegap or Rhomobile.

Does anybody know about these tools, and whether it is possible to develop native apps for iPhone by using these? If possible, does the App Store accept apps written using these tools?

Comment: I've rewritten your question to vaguely resemble coherent English, but I think you're still a little bit confused. I'll let answerers attempt to help you with that.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are referring to web apps, which approximate native apps. The front end, which is used on the mobile device, is written Javascript. The back end, if needed, are usually REST data services hosted on typical web servers. The back end can be written in Ruby, PHP, Scala ...

Phonegap wraps your HTML/CSS/JS app by compiling it into a device app. The Apple store has accepted Phonegap apps.

Some rich frameworks to consider: SproutCore, Cappuccino, Sencha Touch(?)

I'm playing with Backbone + jQuery Mobile, which doesn't try to be a desktop-like framework like the ones above. jQuery Mobile is not as full featured, but is lighter and leverages my current HTML5/JS/CSS skills.

Answer (score 0):

I use Rhomobile to develop apps, it uses Ruby, html, css and other hooks into the phone's native cababilities.  The benefit is that you can build an app once, and deply it for iPhone, iPad, Droid, Windows etc (with just a few tweaks) - you can download the app I developed with Rhodes (Rhomobile's framework) from the app stored.  its called iMessiah - an app for Messiah College, here in PA.

It has admissions department information, apply now (not that you'd complete the application on the phone, but you could), sports scores, integrated 3D campus map, department directories (uses the phones database), touch dial, news, schedule a visit ...

if you don't want to install it - you can check it out here - http://www.messiah.edu/mobile/iMessiah/index.html

-Jon